# Splash Screen on Raspberry pi Display error

Tags: python, tkinter

i am running the following code to get a Splash Screen. But when I run this Code Imag does not appears .It only shows the Frame title and a Blank Frame. Rest of the code runs normal. After 6 seconds it destroys this frame and loads the main frame.
**I am running this on a linux System (Raspberry Pi)**

```
def getFilePath(directory):


   print("Trying File Opened")

   THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
   config_file_path = os.path.join(THIS_FOLDER, directory)
   print(config_file_path)

   return config_file_path

class Splash(tk.Toplevel):


def __init__(self, parent):
    global THIS_FOLDER 
    THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    self.root = tk.Toplevel
    parent.title("Splash")
    parent.geometry("600x500+577+97")
    self.center(parent)
    parent.overrideredirect(1)
    self.ImageLabel = tk.Label(parent)


    self.LogoImage = tk.PhotoImage(file=getFilePath("icons/stop.png")).subsample(5,5) 



    self.ImageLabel.configure(image=self.LogoImage)
    self.ImageLabel.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1
            , relwidth=1)
    ## required to make window show before the program gets to the mainloop
    parent.update()

    time.sleep(6)

    ## finished loading so destroy splash
    self.quit()


def center(self,win):
    """
    centers a tkinter window
    :param win: the root or Toplevel window to center
    """
    win.update_idletasks()
    width = win.winfo_width()
    frm_width = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    win_width = width + 2 * frm_width
    height = win.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()
    win_height = height + titlebar_height + frm_width
    x = win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - win_width // 2
    y = win.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - win_height // 2
    win.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    win.deiconify()

def quit(self):
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    print("coming destroy")
    w.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkInitialPorts()
    vp_start_selector()
############### GUI CODE ENDS ############################
```

Comment: probably problem with bug in PhotoImage which removes image from memory and you see empty place. See note in doc: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: @furas: no, they are saving a reference to the image.

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? You're not properly initializing your class, and you're explicitly putting the label in the parent window rather than the instance of `Splash`. You're also setting `self.root` to a class rather than a widget.

Comment: `time.sleep(6)` blocks the main thread of tkinter and so your GUI will freeze for a good 6 seconds. You need to look into other methods, either by `Thread` or `root.after`.